# Django помощь с хостингом

Tags: django, django-cms

Всем привет. Вопрос следующий. 
Подскажите хостинг по Django по адекватной цене. Именно хостинг. 
Столкнулся с проблемой что кроме выделенных серверов ничего нету, а для простого блога или не крупного магазина, смысла в них не вижу.
Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: [locum.ru](https://locum.ru)

Comment: Жалко двести рублей на сервер?

Comment: @andreymal Я новичек и поэтому спрашиваю, я просто находил сервера, которые стоят 1 882 рублей в месяц, на линуксе минимум 900 по сравнению с хостингом 300. Возможно я не на то смотрел, поэтому и спрашиваю у знающих людей. Буду благодарен если раскроете эту тему в ответе. Спасибо.

Comment: Гуглите VDS/VPS, они в месяц стоят как пару обедов в макдональдсе)

Comment: @andreymal Благодарю за помощь.